# Is it possible to compile programs in visual studio which are created in CCS ver8.0

Tags: visual-studio, microcontroller, msp430

I have implemented MSP430F2418 controller program in Code Composer Studio version 8.0. Now I want to use the same code in Visual Studio 2017. Is it possible to use visual studio?

If it is possible, kindly give information how to run in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Corrected spelling

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Use Visual studio to build the code to run on the MSP or to recompile the code to run on the pc, presumably in a test harness?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know easy ways but you can use the following resources:

- You can check the [VisualGDB project](https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/msp430/). The bad news - isn't free :(
- Also, you can look into [platformio](http://platformio.org) and integration with Visual Studio http://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/ide/visualstudio.html and use this approach for your purposes.

Anyway, you should move C-Files and preprocessor defines to VS project by manually

Comment: Hi denis krasutski, sorry for delay replay, i installed platformIo, but in platformIo doesn't have MSP430F2418 board is not available, is there any way to install the F2418 board, I searched in google but i am not getting any information